# Regular tensorflow ops not supported by the interpreter error during inference

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I am currently trying to convert a saved model trained using Tensorflow (v2.7.0) and Keras to a Tensorflow Lite model. The structure of the model is the following:

```
model_lstm = Sequential()
model_lstm.add(Masking(mask_value=max_int, input_shape=(15, 4)))
model_lstm.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(70, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(Dense(70, activation = "relu"))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(Dense(40, activation = "relu"))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(Dense(5, activation = "relu"))
model_lstm.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4, activation = "softmax")))
```

The model conversion, performed using the following code fragment succeeds, meaning no error is thrown and the converted model is written to the output file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("model_42t_traces")
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
 tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
 tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

However, when trying to perform an inference on a dummy/test input tensor, consisting of a single element of the desired shape, therefore (1,15,4), using the following code

```
interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path="../model.tflite")
my_signature = interpreter.get_signature_runner()
fake_input = np.full((1,15,4), 1.0, dtype=np.float32)
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, fake_input)
interpreter.invoke()
```

the last instruction returns the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Regular TensorFlow ops are not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference.Node number 13 (FlexTensorListFromTensor) failed to prepare.
```

If instead I remove the support to SELECT_TF_OPS during the conversion, the following error arises:

```
ConverterError: <unknown>:0: error: loc(callsite(callsite(
callsite("TensorArrayV2_1@__inference_standard_lstm_292964" at 
"sequential_3/bidirectional_9/backward_lstm_9            
/PartitionedCall@__inference__wrapped_model_301404") at
"StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper_318788")
at "StatefulPartitionedCall")): 'tf.TensorListReserve' op 
requires element_shape to be static during TF Lite 
transformation pass
<unknown>:0: note: loc("StatefulPartitionedCall"): called from
<unknown>:0: error: loc(callsite(callsite(
callsite("TensorArrayV2_1@__inference_standard_lstm_292964" at "s
equential_3/bidirectional_9/backward_lstm_9/PartitionedCall@__inf
erence__wrapped_model_301404") at 
"StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper_318788") 
at "StatefulPartitionedCall")): failed to legalize operation 
'tf.TensorListReserve' that was explicitly marked illegal
<unknown>:0: note: loc("StatefulPartitionedCall"): called from
<unknown>:0: error: Lowering tensor list ops is failed. Please 
consider using Select TF ops and disabling 
`_experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops` flag in the TFLite 
converter object. For example, 
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]\n 
converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
```

Do you have any idea on why this is happening? Am I missing some steps or did I encounter a layer which is currently not yet supported by Tensorflow Lite (without recognising it)?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Python version: 3.7.8
Tensorflow version: 2.7.0 (used both for training and conversion)

Comment: at the bottom it is stated that you can use 
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]\n 
converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
Have you used this combination??

Answer (score 0):

Are you not using Pip package. TFLite Select should be available in pip [already](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#python).

I tried your example in colab and installed 2.7 and working as expected. I think you have something wrong in your setup.

The code example i tried is below

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__

model_lstm = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(input_shape=(15, 4)))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(70, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(70, activation = "relu"))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, activation = "relu"))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation = "relu"))
model_lstm.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation = "softmax")))

# Convert model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model_lstm)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
 tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
 tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
model_content = converter.convert()

# Run the model
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=model_content)
my_signature = interpreter.get_signature_runner()
fake_input = np.full((1,15,4), 1.0, dtype=np.float32)
output = my_signature(masking_input=fake_input)
print(output)
```